# string "if" statement comparing is string empty

Tags: command-line, scripts, sh, dash-shell

I have problem checking if string is empty. 
I get first column of `ls -l` info and try to `grep` string searching for "x". If string is empty, I should countinue. But whenver string is empty or not, I still get my exit code 0 for this if statement.

If I the use command `ls -l $1 | awk '{print $1}'`, I get `-rw-r--r--`
and when I grep it, I get an empty string.

```
#!/bin/sh

test= ` ls -l $1 | awk '{print $1}' | grep x ` ;
if [ -n $test ];
echo "file is not executable";
```

Notes:

1. script is used for academic purposes to get code working without [ -x file ] option.
2. script is written in shell not bash.
3. If you are too lazy to scroll down there is fixed code fragment:

   ```
     #!/bin/sh
     PartOfString=` file $1 | awk '{print $2}' `;
     if [ $PartOfString == executable ];
     then
     echo "file is executable";
     else
     echo "file is not executable or its not file";
     fi
   ```

Comment: Academic purpose aka homework ?

Comment: Getting ready for some data manipulation test. but you can call it homework I guess.

Comment: I didint asked to do it for me =]

Comment: **[Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)**, also [Useless use of `awk | grep`](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#grep).

Comment: This sound like an [XY Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271411). What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you are using has a few issues:

1. It is not recommended to parse `ls`, but let's keep it for now since it has nothing to do with your problem.
2. Using ``` `` ``` to execute your commands works, but is old style and should be replaced wit `$()`. Not very important here, but maybe worth mentioning for the future.
3. Your `if`-construct has the wrong syntax. It is missing a `then` and a `fi`.
4. The way you are using `-n` is wrong. `-n` tests if a string is *not* empty.

Here is an improved version:

```
#!/bin/sh                                       

testString=$(ls -l $1 | awk '{print $1}' | grep x)
if [ -n "$testString" ]
then
    echo "file is executable"
else
    echo "file is not executable"
fi
```

---

The question is about string manipulation and uses the executable flag only as example, but I still want to mention the recommended way to check if a file is executable:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="$1"

if [[ -x "$file" ]]
then
    echo "File '$file' is executable"
else
    echo "File '$file' is not executable or found"
fi
```

Comment: using -x is not an option for me. My syntax is right since i use /sh not /bash. My question would be how to compare if permision section has x letter or not.

Comment: why is `-x` not possible? " My question would be how to compare is permision secion has x letter or not" -> that's exactly what `-x` does...

Comment: I know :D but I'm learning text manipulation, and the idea is to get this "-rw-r----" part and check if it got x letter or not. Im stuck on this for some time.

Comment: @PauliusMickus see my edit

Comment: There's a command called test, id suggest avoiding naming variables same as system executables, unless you want to explicitly override Its functionality

Comment: true, didn't think of this. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's unnecessary to use ls and awk for testing if file is executable , use -x flag with test

```
  [ -x $1 ] && echo executable || echo not executable
```

Answer (score 0):

So I have finally found solution.

now code fragment looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

test=` file $1 | awk '{print $2}' `;
if [ $test == executable ];
then
echo "file is executable";
else
echo "file is not executable or its not file";
fi
```

note that it's expected that first argument is the file you want to check. The idea of this code is to check if file is executable by not using -x option. If you looking for productive code and not for academic one, use Wayne_Yux method described before.